# Alfresco server gets startup gets hung

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to start a Alfresco server but it got hung in between,Please see below screenshot, I have copied Alfresco instance from one server to another server, I have also made necessary changes in Alfresco-global.properties.

Please help on this

[image]

Comment: How did you copy the instance? You have to migrate the alf_data, indexes and database along with the customization to the new alfresco instance.

Comment: I copied installed alfresco folder from c drive to desired server's C drive also copied alf-data folder into appropriate folder. and then started the server.

Comment: Why such an old version of Tomcat? What version of Alfresco is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For backup of your database and alf_data you can download and run the following script.
http://www.contcentric.com/alfresco-backup/
Note: you will have to manually backup the indexes from the solr4 folder and other customizations (like amps and jar deployed)

```
Follow the alfresco restore steps 
1. Install new alfresco instance. Do not start server
2. Start postgresql using the following command
    ./alfresco.sh start postgresql
3. Go to the <ALF-HOME>/postgresql/bin
4. Run the following commmand
    psql -U alfresco -h <hostname> -p port
    e.g.  psql -U alfresco -h localhost -p 5422
5. It will ask you to set the password, enter the password and remember it
6. Run the following command

     psql -U alfresco -h <host> -p port <dbname> < dumpFile
     e.g.     psql -U alfresco -h localhost -p 5422 alfresco < /opt/migration-backup/01-10-2018-15-54-47/database/alfresco_db_dump

7. You will notice the multiple tables and index are created
8. Start the tomcat using the following command

     ./alfresco.sh start tomcat

9. Test your migration.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. One question, Can I give shared drive path in alfresco-global.properties for dir.root variable for content store.